# Grouping or manipulating laravel collections

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I'm working on a laravel project where

a **customer** has many **bookings** and **ticket_records**

**ticket_record** and **booking** both belong to an **event**

here is the overall structure

```
customers
    id - integer
    name - string

events
    id - integer
    title - string

booking
    event_id - integer
    customer_id - integer
    room_id - integer

ticket_records
    event_id - integer
    customer_id - integer
    activity_id - integer
    tickets - integer
```

customer can have more than one booking for an event. customer can also have more than one ticket records for an event.

In the customer show method, I want to show a card for each event the customer has made a booking with all the bookings and ticket_records of that customer for that event. So that the customer show method looks something like..

```
- event
  - booking
  - ticket_record
  - ticket_record

- event
  - booking
  - booking
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is okay. But this is how i have done it and it finally works!

```
$callback = fn($query) => $query->where('customer_id', $customer_id);

$bookedEvents = ScheduledEvent::whereHas('bookingRecords', $callback)
        ->with(['bookingRecords' => $callback, 'ticketRecords' => $callback])
        ->orderby('date')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much information on how your models link up and the hierarchy of them, so lets say you have `customer_id` on your `events` table and `event_id` on both your bookings and tickets tables.

You can use relationships to achieve what you want:

Inside your `Customer` model you need to add a relationship to events.

```
public function events()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Event::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

Then inside your `Event` model you need two relationships for tickets & bookings

```
public function bookings()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class, 'event_id', 'id');
}

public function tickets()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class, 'event_id', 'id');
}
```

Now, if you have a `Customer` model, you will be able to write some logic to get the bookings and tickets for each event.

```
public function getCustomerBookings()
{
    $customers = Customer::with('events, events.bookings, events.tickets')->get();

    //example

    foreach($customers as $customer) {
        $events = $customer->events;

        foreach($events as $event) {
            $event->bookings;
            $event->tickets;
        }
    }
}
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships for more information

Comment: Does that line ```$customers = Customer::with('events, events.bookings, events.tickets')->get();``` will only retrieve the events.bookings that have the customer_id? If yes, after 6 years using Laravel, i think you just blown my mind.

Comment: yes that is the case, you will get an array of customers and for each one you will be able to do $customer->events which has `their` events :)

Comment: Thank you, you bring me to 2020.

Comment: @Ballard sorry for not adding more information in my question. I'm really new at this. But i have edited my question with little more detail. Thanks for the help